# Responsive menu button missing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem when trying to make my menu responsive with bootstrap.
The normal button with the three lines don't appear.

[Se the development site here.](http://mautone.dk/sandbox/stef/)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Best regards
Daniel Mautone

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the normal button with the three lines" and post specific code.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, please can you create an [MCVE] in the question as links may die in furture - see this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: The button DOES appear, it seems to be invisible but clickable. Use your browser's developer tools to play around with the buttons' css a little.

Comment: The burger button was simply just invisible according to the css.